# Why does the android apk size differs when built from windows and mac

Tags: android, eclipse, windows, macos, apk

We are a group of developers who are using windows and mac machine for android development. Apparently there is a size difference in the apk when built from windows and mac. There is an additional 300k which gets added to the apk when built from mac.

We are using eclipse with the adt plugin for android development.

Is this a known issue ? Is there some way by which we can remove this extra size from the apk ?

Comment: Maybe there is a __MACOSX Directory inside your .apk? This directory is created if you create an archive in mac os x.

Comment: These are the list of directories which were present when i unzipped thr apk.. AndroidManifest.xml,META-INF,assets ,classes.dex ,com,js,lib,org,res,resources.arsc.

Comment: Have you unzipped the apk in Windows? Because __MACOSX is not visible in Mac OS X

Comment: did anyone found out how to ignore __MACOSX folder while creating apk?

Comment: Once I imported an android project from mac to ubuntu and there it shows many mac related files starting with . .There was almost a dot file for every class in app

Answer (score 11):

It is because Apple & Microsoft define gigabyte differently. Microsoft defines 1GB as 1024 MB, whereas Apple defines 1GB as 1000 MB.

So, as the size of the content of Res vary the size of Apk will also vary.

You can refer this link for more details on size.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte

Comment: Why Apple is making this difference in binary world ? Think in binary.

Answer (score 1):

Windows defines 1KB as 1024 Bytes, Mac/Apple defines 1KB as 1000 Bytes, that's where your size difference should come from. Which means that when you transfer your apk file to android device from both Mac and Windows, **on android both should be same size**.

Comment: I get a difference of 6mb

Comment: @Fahim huh, how big is your apk file then?

Comment: 13 mb on mac when created and 7-8 mb when created from windows machine

Comment: @Fahim, did you find the answer to your question, were there additional folders in your build?